# Finding all words that contain a given substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and am intending to write a function that writes to the document all strings from an array that contain as a substring the string that is currently entered into the input text field.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" >
    <p></p>
<script>

    var names = ["armadillo", "blue", "com", "demo", "engine"];

    $("input").keypress(function() {
    var incomplete = $( this ).val();

    searchStrings();

    };

    function(searchStrings())
    {
        for(name in names)
        {
            if(name.indexOf(incomplete) != -1)
            {
                document.write(name);
            } else
            {
                document.write("no match found");
            }
        }
    };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `function(searchStrings())` is probably your problem. You have too many parenthesis. You should also pass the value into your function.

Comment: Are you trying to develop [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) from scratch? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DrekX/

Since you are using jQuery use it to it's fullest.

```
var names = ["armadillo", "blue", "com", "demo", "engine"];

// references to jQuery belong in a wrapper

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("input").keyup(function() {        
        searchStrings(this.value);
    });

    function searchStrings( search_value )
    {
        if(!search_value.length){
            $('#names-found').html('');
            return;
        }

        var names_found = $.map(names, function( value, index ){            
            return ~value.indexOf(search_value) ? value : null;
        });

        $('#names-found').html(
            names_found.length == 0 ? 'No names found.' :
            '<b>Names found:</b> ' + names_found.join(', ')
        )        
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show me how to append those matched words into a list?  I am trying to figure out how to make an autocomplete function, mostly out of curiosity.  Your answer was awesome.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Up vote awesome answers. I had a feeling that is where you were headed. Check out http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your `searchStrings()` function so it takes an argument:

```
function searchStrings(incomplete)
{
    for(name in names)
    {
        if(name.indexOf(incomplete) != -1)
        {
            document.write(name);
        } else
        {
            document.write("no match found");
        }
    }
};
```

And you need to call it like this:

```
searchStrings(incomplete);
```

Fixing your syntax errors, your code should look like this:

```
var names = ["armadillo", "blue", "com", "demo", "engine"];

function searchStrings(incomplete) {
    for (name in names) {
        if (name.indexOf(incomplete) != -1) {
            alert(name);
        } else {
            alert("no match found");
        }
    }
};

$("input").keyup(function () {
    var incomplete = $(this).val();
    searchStrings(incomplete);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyXvE/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your function like this(Remove extra paranthesis)

```
function searchStrings(incomplete)
    {
        for(name in names)
        {
            if(name.indexOf(incomplete) != -1)
            {
                document.write(name);
            } else
            {
                document.write("no match found");
            }
        }
    };
```

and call it like

```
searchStrings(incomplete);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Nothing is being written to the document on keypress even after the changes.